# Using Enum in Model (domain) Class with hibernate - could not resolve property - exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, enums, persistence

In table I am saving integer values for applied, selected, not selected etc...  What I thought is to use Enum in Java Domain class.  I tried implementing it.  While I am calling this domain from DAO, I am getting some weired error.  Please find the code(s) below.

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;
import javax.persistence.*;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
@Entity
@Table(name="xxxxxx")
public class JobApplied{
    public enum RSVP {
        APPLIED_REJECTED(0), 
        APPLIED_SHORTLISTED(1), 
        SHORTLISTED_SELECTED (3),
        SHORTLISTED_IN_PROGRESS (4),
        SHORTLISTED_ON_HOLD (5),
        SHORTLISTED_REJECTED (6);

        private int value;
        RSVP(int value) { this.value = value; }    
        public int getValue() { return value; }
        public static RSVP parse(int id) {
            RSVP rsvp = null;
            for (RSVP item : RSVP.values()) {
                if (item.getValue()==id) {
                    rsvp = item;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return rsvp;
        }
    };

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="job_opportunity_id")
    @NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private JobOpportunity jobOpportunity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @NotFound(action= NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Users users;

    @Column(name="status")
    private int RSVP_Status;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public JobOpportunity getJobOpportunity()
    {
        return jobOpportunity;
    }
    public void setJobOpportunity(JobOpportunity jobOpportunity)
    {
        this.jobOpportunity=jobOpportunity;
    }

    public Users getUsers()
    {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Users users){
        this.users=users;
    } 

    public RSVP getRSVP_Status () {
        return RSVP.parse(this.RSVP_Status);
    }   
    public void setRSVP_Status(RSVP rsvp) {
        this.RSVP_Status = rsvp.getValue();
    }
    public void setRSVP_Status(int rSVP_Status) {
        RSVP_Status = RSVP.parse(rSVP_Status).getValue();
    }   
}
```

While calling the above domain class using this method,

```
public List<JobApplied> getAppliedCandidates(long jobId) {
        Map<String, Object> conditions = getConditionsTemplate();
        conditions.put("status", (Integer)JobApplied.RSVP.APPLIED_SHORTLISTED.getValue());
        //Error is not because of the above line.
        conditions.put("jobOpportunity.jobOpportunityId", jobId);
        return findByCriteria(null, conditions); //stack trace points the error in this line.
}
```

I am getting this error,

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: status of: com.xxxx.xxxxx.domain.JobApplied
```

Kindly clear me where I am wrong.  Hope my question is clear.  Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change in Enum**

```
public enum RSVP {
    APPLIED_REJECTED, 
    APPLIED_SHORTLISTED, 
    SHORTLISTED_SELECTED, 
    SHORTLISTED_IN_PROGRESS, 
    SHORTLISTED_ON_HOLD, 
    SHORTLISTED_REJECTED;

    private int status;

    public int getValue() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

**Change in Domain Class**

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name="status")
    private RSVP rsvpStatus;

    public RSVP getRsvpStatus() {
        return this.rsvpStatus;
    }

    public void setRsvpStatus(RSVP rsvp) {
        this.rsvpStatus = rsvp;
    }
```

**Change in DAO Call**

```
conditions.put("rsvpStatus", RSVP.APPLIED_SHORTLISTED);
```

**Change in Table**

```
Keep "status" column in table as int datatype
```

It's very easy to integrate Enum Type in Hibernate.If you annotate with EnumType.STRING then it will store string values in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your property "status" doesn't have any getter/setter anymore. Hibernate needs these to be able to access the underlying instance variable RSVP_Status. So you would need this:

```
int getStatus() { return RSVP_Status; }
void setStatus(int status) { RSVP_Status = status; }
```

Comment: I have changed my answer, please have another try with this

Comment: never mind. Glad you found it. Please share with us what the problem was.

Comment: Sorry for behaving very straight forward regarding my last comment which might hurt you.  I need to Thank you for your valuable time spent for me.   Sorry again.  Please find the corrections on code below.

Comment: no hard feelings. Thanks for adding the solution, which can surely help others in the future